# Connecting to Sharepoint Online returns 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, search, sharepoint, office365

I am trying to perform a Sharepoint Online search using the C# API:

```
var clientContext =
    new ClientContext("https://foobar.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Shared%20Documents");
var pw = "apassword";
var secure = new SecureString();
foreach (var c in pw) secure.AppendChar(c);

var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("adress@mail.com", secure);
clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";
var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
var results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I get the response '401: Unauthorized', although the credentials I've provided are correct. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a SharePoint document library (https://foobar.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Shared%20Documents). Try to connect to "https://foobar.sharepoint.com/".

Also the client context might not have enough permissions to perform the search.

Comment: Everything is working now, although I haven't changed anything. It might have been a server or connection issue. Your point is right though, I posted the code while trying different things and didn't change the domain back to the plain version. With the version I've posted I now get an exception which makes sense, saying that a connection to this site couldn't be established. Thank you for your help!